# Is there any Intellisense support available for SparkView Engine for VB.Net

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, spark-view-engine

Is there any Intellisense support available for SparkView Engine for VB.Net .

The [Intellisense](http://sparkviewengine.com/usage/intellisense) is currently available with SparkView Engine. But it is for C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently no, and there is none planned for Visual Studio 2008. Depending on how much need there is for it, I can look at including support for it in [SparkSense](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef944259-fc8a-42e0-838e-f397957e1d11) which only works on VS2010 (due to the fact that it uses the new MEF plugin model)